# How to club multiple .csv files from a folder and load the data into a single table using forloop of SSIS Package?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a folder that has many .csv files. Now I want to club the files and bring the data into a destination table.

I have used DFT that uses a flat file source that takes only a single file and loads the data to a destination table. How can I use this Flat file source to collect multiple files from the same folder and load it into a single table at the destination?

How to use a flat file source and for loop in combination here?
Please help me in implementing this.

Comment: There are dozens of online guides for this. Here's one. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid. I'll read this.